# C# math libraries that operate on simple vectors and arrays

Tags: c#, math

There are several math libraries for c#, but they all seem to either define their own vector and matrix types, or operate on established c# classes like Vector3D or Vector.

Are there any math libraries that operate on "simple" vector and matrix types such as double[] and double[,]

Some example of "nice to have" functions would be

```
double[] v = new double[3];
double[] w = new double[3];
double m[,] = new double[3,3];

double vDOTv = DesiredClass.Dot(v); // v.v

double[] normV = DesiredClass.Normalize(v); // normalize vector

double[] cCROSSw = DesiredClass.Cross(v,w);  // v x w

double vDOTm = DesiredClass.Dot(v,m,i); // v.m[i] - dot product of v with ith row of m
```

Comment: I have inherited a set of classes to maintain that have a lot of these types of data structures around

Comment: what do you exactly wanna to do? Be more Specific.

Comment: I want to do all the common vector/matrix operations (dot product, cross product, norm, magnitude, determinant). Operation one would expect a good math library.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.Net Numerics](http://api.mathdotnet.com/Numerics/MathNet.Numerics.Algorithms.LinearAlgebra/ManagedLinearAlgebraProvider.htm) provides various matrix methods including MatrixMultiply and MatrixNorm, that work on `double[]`, so it looks like it does most of what you need. I couldn't see the dot product, but it might be under a different name I'm unaware of.

Comment: Certainly a possibility, but I notice that is requires a user to construct a matrix from a 2d array. I was curious to see if there were libraries that operated on the 2d array *directly*, without being forced to create someone's matrix implementation.

Comment: FYI: [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com) Matrix and Vector types do operate directly on normal 2D arrays (column-major order for matrices). Btw, Math.NET Numerics replaces Iridium (what you've linked to), that's why Iridium is no longer being updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own classes for these types and provide them with implicit conversion from and to double arrays, then create those utility methods accepting parameters of your own type that would work on those arrays since there is an implicit conversion.

But that would be a bit fishy, why not work on normal types already.